# Aggregate records with peewee and Python

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm trying to learn Python and have problem to understand how to use the aggregate functions with peewee.

In my code I first do imports like:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from peewee import *
from database import (db_init, MF_Djur, MF_Logg, MF_Senaste_Koll, MF_Foderspec)
```

To test if peewee and database connection works, I have used the following code successfully:

```
antalgivor24h = MF_Logg.select() \
        .where((MF_Logg.Logg_RFID_ID == tag_no) & (MF_Logg.Logg_Tid > timelastday)).count()
print(antalgivor24h)
```

**To my problem:** I would like to use sum function and this is where I get problems. I want to do this sql in peewee format:

```
SELECT SUM(`Logg_Giva_Foder1`) 
FROM mf_logg 
WHERE `Logg_RFID_ID`='752007904107005' AND `Logg_Tid` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

In peewee docs (http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#aggregating-records) I have seen the following example code:

```
query = (User
         .select()
         .annotate(
             Tweet,
             fn.Max(Tweet.created_date).alias('latest_tweet_date')))
```

Based on this I tried:

```
totalgiva124h = MF_Logg.select() \
        .where((MF_Logg.Logg_RFID_ID == tag_no) & (MF_Logg.Logg_Tid > timelastday)) \
        .annotate(MF_Logg, fn.Sum(MF_Logg.Logg_Giva_Foder1))
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testscript.py", line 32, in <module>
    .annotate(MF_Logg, fn.Sum(MF_Logg.Logg_Giva_Foder1))
NameError: name 'fn' is not defined
```

I have googled this error but for peewee aggregate records I couldn't get much help (on general Python nameerrors I found a lot but nothing that helped me). However, on one page I read that it could help importing peewee fn separately. I therefore tried adding

```
from peewee import *, fn
```

but then I get the following error, so no luck:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testscript.py", line 32, in <module>
    .annotate(MF_Logg, fn.Sum(MF_Logg.Logg_Giva_Foder1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 1763, in annotate
    query = query.ensure_join(query._query_ctx, rel_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 1522, in ensure_join
    query = self.switch(lm).join(rm, on=on).switch(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 199, in inner
    func(clone, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 1505, in join
    self._query_ctx, model_class))
ValueError: No foreign key between <class 'database.MF_Logg'> and <class 'database.MF_Logg'>
```

I hope someone knows how to write the query in a correct way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate is not what you want in this case. Instead try:

```
MF_Logg.select(fn.SUM(MF_Logg.Logg_Giva_Foder1)) \
    .where((MF_Logg.Logg_RFID_ID == tag_no) & (MF_Logg.Logg_Tid > timelastday)) \
    .scalar()
```

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#retrieving-scalar-values

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your solution works fine and I will now read more about scalar(). :)